# I am using ngFor on Array of objects and in html the data is not displaying

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular6, ngfor

I am new to angular and stuff.

Below is the format of the array which is I am getting in the console.

```
[]
0: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dae", name: "Andhra Pradesh", abbvr: "AP"}
1: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61daf", name: "Arunachal Pradesh", abbvr: "AR"}
2: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db1", name: "Bihar", abbvr: "BR"}
3: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db6", name: "Gujarat", abbvr: "GJ"}
4: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db3", name: "Chhattisgarh", abbvr: "CG"}
5: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db8", name: "Himachal Pradesh", abbvr: "HP"}
6: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dbb", name: "Karnataka", abbvr: "KA"}
7: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dbd", name: "Madhya Pradesh", abbvr: "MP"}
8: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc0", name: "Odisha", abbvr: "OR"}
9: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc2", name: "Punjab", abbvr: "PB"}
10: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc5", name: "Tamil Nadu", abbvr: "TN"}
11: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc7", name: "Tripura", abbvr: "TR"}
12: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dca", name: "West Bengal", abbvr: "WB"}
13: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db2", name: "Chandigarh", abbvr: "CD"}
14: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dcc", name: "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", abbvr: "AN"}
15: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db7", name: "Haryana", abbvr: "HR"}
16: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dbc", name: "Kerala", abbvr: "KL"}
17: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc1", name: "Puducherry", abbvr: "PY"}
18: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc6", name: "Telangana", abbvr: "TL"}
19: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dcb", name: "Manipur", abbvr: "MN"}
20: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db0", name: "Assam", abbvr: "AS"}
21: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db4", name: "Delhi", abbvr: "DL"}
22: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db9", name: "Jammu and Kashmir", abbvr: "JK"}
23: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61db5", name: "Goa", abbvr: "GA"}
24: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dbe", name: "Maharashtra", abbvr: "MH"}
25: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc3", name: "Rajasthan", abbvr: "RJ"}
26: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dba", name: "Jharkhand", abbvr: "JH"}
27: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dbf", name: "Meghalaya", abbvr: "ML"}
28: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc8", name: "Uttar Pradesh", abbvr: "UP"}
29: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dcd", name: "Mizoram", abbvr: "MZ"}
30: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc4", name: "Sikkim", abbvr: "SK"}
31: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dc9", name: "Uttarakhand", abbvr: "UK"}
32: {_id: "5b90fb38345c932d46e61dce", name: "Nagaland", abbvr: "NL"}
```

and HTML for the ngFor is:

```
<option  *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.name">{{state.name}}</option>
```

In display there is number of option but nothing is visible when i am printing in console it shows undefined

Edit 1:
Below is the code of components which uses service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {VenueService} from './venue.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-workshop',
  templateUrl: './workshop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workshop.component.css']
})
export class WorkshopComponent  {
states=[];
  constructor(private venueService: VenueService) {

  }
  ngOnInit(){
   this.venueService.getStates().subscribe(state => {
     state.forEach(entry=>{
       this.states.push(entry);
     });
    });
    console.log(this.states);
  }

}
```

Edit 2: I am Using Observable during api call and Interface,
so this would be my service method looks like:

```
getStates(): Observable<State[]>{
return http.get<State[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/getstate');
 }
```

Comment: can you add the code of how assigning the data to the `states` var?

Comment: Yes added component part do u want to see service part too?

Comment: Is fine. I solved your problem but I can't see even this example in my browser: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp. It's just empty

Comment: You said: `Below is the format of the array which is I am getting in the console.` and there is data in the array. Later you say: `[...] when i am printing in console it shows undefined`. This does not make sense. So when you log the array in the console, does it display the data or not?

Comment: The console.log should be inside the subscription.

Comment: Why are you looping the `state` (which by the way is a bad name since you have more than one state) and then just pushing the same values to another array? 
You could just do `this.states = state` ..

Comment: @L.Guthardt the data is printed from component not from html when i use normal ul li it shows null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the Observable directly from your service, as your example suggests, then the answer by Joseph Webber gets my vote.

However, if you want to perform some processing on the result first, then you can notify angular to detect your change, by calling `detectChanges` on the component's change detector.

For example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { VenueService } from './venue.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-workshop',
  templateUrl: './workshop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workshop.component.css']
})
export class WorkshopComponent implements OnInit  {
  states = [];
  constructor(private venueService: VenueService,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.venueService.getStates().subscribe(state => {
      // Do some stuff with the results ... 
      state.forEach(entry => {
        this.states.push(entry);
      });
      // Let angular know.
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  });
  console.log(this.states);
 }
}
```

Comment: Okay this works and all other doesn't, so my question why there isnt a proper documentation of iteration and observable in Angular this is so messy.

Comment: also it works without changeDetector too there was other angular error because of model binding so the data was not displaying in html.

Answer (score 4):

It should show an empty array because you have an async method if you want to display a array after the method you must use aysnc /wait or asyn pip in html:

```js
  async ngOnInit()
  {     const states= await                               
       this.venueService.getStates().toPromise();
        console.log(states);
  }
```

```html
<option  *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.name">{{state.name}}</option>
```

**For second way:**

it already mentioned  in first Answer

Comment: not using promise it's not working. can you explain why use toPromise? using rxjs 6.3.x and angular 6

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<option  *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">{{state.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

`venueService.getStates()` is `asynchronous` function.

Try below.

```
  ngOnInit(){
   this.venueService.getStates()
         .subscribe(state => {
             state.forEach(entry=>{
               this.states.push(entry);
           });
         console.log(this.states);
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `async` pipe in your HTML and set `states` to the observable returned from your service.

```html
<option *ngFor="let state of states | async" [value]="state.name">{{state.name}}</option>
```

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.states = this.venueService.getStates();
}
```